# Excel: Converting Decimals to M:SS:000

Tags: excel, time, decimal, type-conversion

I'm looking to convert decimals into the format m:ss:000 or mm:ss:000. Either is fine. Here are a few examples of the input and the desired output:

- Input: 0.045173611 Output: 0:50.903
- Input: 0.044722222 Output: 0:50.864
- Input: 0.042256944 Output: 0:50.651

I understand that the decimal input is a representation of how many days have gone by, but I just can't get the formula right. Thanks for any help you may have!

Comment: `0.045173611` is `01:05:03` in excel. How and where did you get `0:50.903`?

Comment: Ahh, I've found my error. My source csv text file had `0:50:903` for each. I then pasted the source file into Excel and it automatically converted them into decimals. Instead of having `:903`, I needed to have them as `.903`.

Answer (score 0):

Either just set the format of the cell to `mm:ss.000` or use `=TEXT(Input, "mm:ss.000")`

For example, `=TEXT(NOW(), "mm:ss.000")` would return `04:30.572`